# ActionBarActivity catch an error on Phone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

**
I was recomended to use ActionBar Activity**
Here is the previous code

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    }
```

I wrote new application and followed advice.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
          }

        }
```

*if I use ACtionBarActivity instead of Activity

I catch an error message on phone, when I try to run it.*
Please tell me what I do wrong

info from Logcat

```
    07-27 15:14:19.942: I/Process(21715): Sending signal. PID: 21715 SIG: 9
07-27 15:34:38.521: W/dalvikvm(23579): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/project/MainActivity; (532)
07-27 15:34:38.521: W/dalvikvm(23579): Link of class 'Lcom/example/project/MainActivity;' failed
07-27 15:34:38.521: D/AndroidRuntime(23579): Shutting down VM
07-27 15:34:38.521: W/dalvikvm(23579): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ae5210)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.project.MainActivity
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.project.MainActivity
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
07-27 15:34:38.521: E/AndroidRuntime(23579):    ... 11 more
07-27 15:34:38.531: I/Process(23579): Sending signal. PID: 23579 SIG: 9
```

edit and export screenshot
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNfc1.jpg

screenshot of 1-7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpP3.jpg

Comment: Please post your stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: I posted this information.

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i added screenshots of Order and Export and Projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it worked after moving "Android Private Libraries" and "Android Dependencies" to the top of the list in Order and Export in my application project.
Also I dont have android-support-v7-appcompat in this list.
And in the android-support-v7-appcompat project I dont have support jars in the Order and Export list, but "Android Private Libraries" is checked.
Please, check also the links below:

[Setting up ActionBarCompat support library in Eclipse](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-setting-up-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-eclipse/)

[Implementing Action Bar using ActionBarCompat support library in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-action-bar-using-actionbarcompat-support-library-in-android/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I downloaded Android Studio. And one added line forced my project to work.

Comment: Your instruction helped me with Eclipse

Comment: moving android private libraries to the top together with android dependencies and moving them in the top of the list in build path did the trick for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the support library is added to the project and exported. You can do so in Eclipse by viewing the properties of your project, clicking `Java Build Path`, then the `Order and Export` tab. Then make sure `Android Private Libraries` is checked.

Did you follow these steps: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#

Comment: i added screenshots of Order and Export and Projects.

Comment: Did you follow the steps from the page I linked to my answer?

Comment: Of course, but I wasn't sure in the 2th paragraph of the second part. I did it in that way -  i.stack.imgur.com/uBCqz.jpg i.stack.imgur.com/5qSs4.jpg

Comment: Did you follow `Adding libraries with resources` ?

Comment: In the Library pane, click Add. i.stack.imgur.com/uBCqz.jpg i.stack.imgur.com/5qSs4.jpg

Comment: Yes, I followed Adding libraries with resources.

Comment: Do you have both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar as an exported library in your library project? (Steps 5 to 7). You seem to have followed the second part correctly, as far as I can tell from your screenshots.

Comment: I have them in android-support-v7-appcompat project

Comment: I opened project android-support-v7-appcompat and next followed the steps from (1 to 7)

Comment: It doesn't helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same stack trace as you with Android Studio. I think it is caused by Android not being able to find a suitable theme for ActionBarActivity.

Anyway, this is how I solved it:

Add the following to your MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

If it works now - great! If Android Studio cannot find the theme:
Copy the files

```
sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml
sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml
```

to the res/values/ folder in your project.

Comment: Copying those two .xml files leads to over a hundred errors, though.