# How can I test activity based on ActionBarActivity (from android.support.v7.app) using AndroidUnitTestCase<T> class?

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, android-support-library

Sorry for my English.

I use Android Studio. To learn how to create tests in Android Studio I used this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio/16881419#16881419)

All tests are in the same Android App Module where the source.

The support libraries for `v4` and `v7` are connected (`v7` is connected by default).

The module's `build.gradle` contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
}
```

and `support-v4-19.0.0.jar` is shown as external library (in the project tree).

All was right while I used usual `Activity` class (from `android.app` package). But when I use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` as base class for tested activity, then I get error as on the image: [image: error on try to use the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity class as base class for tested activity]

But I already use `Theme.AppCompat` as parent for tested activity's theme:

```
<!-- from AndroidManifest.xml -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ListOfProgressesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and

```
<!-- styles.xml from values (it's the only values folder) -->
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here is stacktrace of the exception:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Progres
sTracker:connectedInstrumentTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec
uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec
ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut
e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter
.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut
e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailur
e(AbstractTask.java:283)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultT
askPlanExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Def
aultCacheAccess.java:214)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Def
aultCacheAccess.java:276)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunning
Operation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStat
eCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(Defaul
tTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(Defau
ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTask
ExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildEx
ecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions
.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the rep
ort at: file:///E:/AndroidProjects/ProgressTrackerProject/ProgressTracker/build/
reports/instrumentTests/connected/index.html
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestT
ask.runTests(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.groovy:90)
        at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:527)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:510)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 52 more
```

Comment: Am I right that you overrides ListActivity in your test? I see `TestListOfProgressActivity` class

Comment: No. Tested Activity has ListView. It extends ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the Context that is used to create the Activities. As the test context is not themed, you must do it yourself.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
    setActivityContext(context);
    activity = startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN), null, null);
}
```